# Node.js - File System get file type, solution around year 2012

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems, file-type

I need to get the file type of a file with the help of Node.js to set the content type. I know I can easily check the file extension, but I've also got files without an extension which should have the content type `image/png` or `text/html`.

This is my code (I know it doesn't make much sense but that's the base I need):

```
var http = require("http"),
    fs = require("fs");
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    var data = "";
    try {
        /*
         * Do not use this code!
         * It's not async and it has a security issue.
         * The code style is also bad.
         */
        data = fs.readFileSync("/home/path/to/folder" + req.url);
        var type = "???"; // how to get the file type??
        res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": type});
    } catch(e) {
        data = "404 Not Found";
        res.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    }
    res.write(data);
    res.end();
}).listen(7000);
```

I haven't found a function for that in [the API](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html), so how can I do it?

Comment: `readFileSync` on on every request? Doesn't sounds like a good idea...

Comment: @ThiefMaster As he said this is only dummy code (at least that's what I think "I know this doesn't make much [sense] but that's the base I need" is supposed to mean).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Have a look at the [mmmagic module](https://github.com/mscdex/mmmagic). It is a libmagic binding and seems to do exactly what you want.

Comment: Assuming `fs.stat` does what `stat` does: How exactly would any of the information you get there help him determine the MIME type of the file?

Comment: I don't actually know, I presume it would tell you something useful :P

Comment: @Raynos: seeing as you have no idea, why did you even comment? This is the best answer yet.

Comment: Try passing the path to a magic file as the first argument to [`new Magic()`](https://github.com/mscdex/mmmagic#magic-methods)

Comment: Any way to get the MIME from a file moving through a pipe and without an underlying file in the file system?  I see this API provides a way to get it from a buffer, but that seems rather heavy-handed since this seems to require the entire file be present and often only the first few bytes of the file need to be examined.

Answer (score 46):

There is a helper library for looking up [MIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) types: *[Mime](https://github.com/broofa/node-mime)*

```
var mime = require('mime');

mime.getType('/path/to/file.txt'); // => 'text/plain'
```

But it still uses the extension for lookup though.

Comment: Actually that library is very nice but as ThiefMaster has commented to timeoxly's answer it's based on file extension so it will download files without extension.

Comment: This does not work for me, mime.lookup is not a function (probably removed)

Comment: Since version 2 "lookup" was renamed to "getType". Source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mime

Comment: when I upload a file from a form, it doesn't have an extension. Also extensions are unreliable to begin with.

Answer (score 9):

You should have a look at the command line tool `file` (Linux). It attempts to guess the filetype based on the first couple of bytes of the file. You can use `child_process.spawn` to run it from within node.

Answer (score 6):

You want to be looking up the mime type, and thankfully node has a handy library just for that:

https://github.com/bentomas/node-mime#readme

edit:

You should probably look into a static asset server and not be setting any of this stuff yourself. You can use [express](https://github.com/visionmedia/express#readme) to do this really easily, or there's a whole host of static file modules, e.g. [ecstatic](https://github.com/jesusabdullah/node-ecstatic). On the other hand you should probably use nginx to serve static files anyway.

Comment: Depending on what he wants to do getting the type based on the filename might not the best idea.

Answer (score 3):

**2018 solution**

The accepted answer appears to have a Python dependency and the other answers are either out-of-date or presume the file name has some sort of extension.

Please find my more up-to-date answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53950321/nodejs-to-get-file-type-of-a-file)

Comment: This is the best answer and should be ***the*** answer. too bad that this six-year-old question is stuck with an outdated answer. ￼ @Stephen, if I ask in a new question, would you care to answer it?

Comment: Sure thing :) I can link this answer to the new one.

Comment: There you go, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53950321/. thx @Stephen.

Comment: Cool, I have answered there.

Answer (score 2):

I used this:

```
npm install mime-types
```

And, inside the code:

```
var mime = require('mime-types');
tmpImg.contentType = mime.lookup(fileImageTmp);
```

Where fileImageTmp is the copy of image stored on the file system (in this case tmp).

The result I can see is: **image/jpeg**

Answer (score 1):

The best approach I believe is using the `file` command of the system, that way you have three advantages:

1. No dependencies,
2. You will make sure through magic numbers the type of content the file has,
3. You will be able to create type of contents through magic files.

Example:

```
let pathToFile = '/path/to/file';
const child_process = require('child_process');
child_process.exec(`"file" ${path}`, (err, res) => {
  let results = res.replace('\n', '').split(':');
  let stringPath = results[0].trim();
  let typeOfFile = results[1].trim();
  console.log(stringPath, typeOfFile);
});
```

Docs:
https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/file.1.html
https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v13.x/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

Answer (score 1):

Following fp007's approach with `file` command utility, this is how I get the file extension of files using nodejs in 2023:

```js
import { exec } from 'child_process'
import { promisify } from 'util'

// async exec, hell yes
const execPromise = promisify(exec)

// using the --brief flag would onmit the filepath in the output
// the --mime-type flag will output mime type strings
// the following command will only output the mimetype of the file
const { stdout: mimetype, stderr } = await execPromise(`file --brief --mime-type ${filepath}`)

console.log('mimetype: ', mimetype)
console.log('stderr: ', stderr)
```

Sources: [Nodejs doc about exec](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_processexeccommand-options-callback) and [ss64 bash doc about file command](https://ss64.com/bash/file.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you need this for something like file upload in web applications, you can just use `file.type` and don't need to install any dependencies.