# Node.js get file extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-type

Im creating a file upload function in node.js with express 3.

I would like to grab the file extension of the image. so i can rename the file and then append the file extension to it.

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res, next) {
    var is = fs.createReadStream(req.files.upload.path),
        fileExt = '', // I want to get the extension of the image here
        os = fs.createWriteStream('public/images/users/' + req.session.adress + '.' + fileExt);
});
```

How can i get the extension of the image in node.js?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431845/node-js-file-system-get-file-type repeat?

Comment: Isn't that question about mime-types, i want the file extension

Answer (score 688, accepted):

I believe you can do the following to get the extension of a file name.

```js
var path = require('path')

path.extname('index.html')
// returns
'.html'
```

If you would like to get all extensions in a file name (e.g. `filename.css.gz` => `css.gz`), try this:

```js
const ext = 'filename.css.gz'
  .split('.')
  .filter(Boolean) // removes empty extensions (e.g. `filename...txt`)
  .slice(1)
  .join('.')

console.log(ext) // prints 'css.gz'
```

Comment: Just be careful, it will only grab the characters after the last dot, so file names like `app.css.gz` will only return `.gz` and not `.css.gz`, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: In that case, simply use `filename.split('.').pop();`

Comment: @AamirAfridi That returns the same string just without the `.`.

Comment: Try `'filename.css.gz'.split('.').slice(1).join('.')` to get _all_ extensions

Comment: Generally the extension is the last one. And for when we are expecting more then one, like tar.gz for example. it's better to check if it exist in the end or not. using regex for example. "tar.gz$" or by building up a function that do that. like checking that from the end and going back and see if it match totally.  and you will have that function that check the extension. **WHY? because  what about files like `jone.lastTest.654654556.tar.gz`   here the extension that's expected is tar.gz but if you apply any function that give form 1st dot, it will not work as you can see**

Comment: @AllalMohamed Not really a problem in your case. `.tar.gz` is just a `.tar` ran through gzip. You can do `gzip -d foo.tar.gz` to get a plain and simple `foo.tar`. The extensions make sense - you don't need to know both extensions at once.

Comment: @Qix: for that i just have given an example. And yea your point make sense and is self explanatory, as interesting as someone can not notice. But imaging what we are doing is not extracting the files, but rather validating them. and making sure we accept only tar.gz and not other format, well the same can apply in other situation, there is a lot of cases where the extension may be more then just one (.blade.php for example). Checking for it is more direct, and we can always do checks level by level. Whatever. Thank you for your comment it's very helpful.

Comment: Won't work if the filename is just '.html' (empty base name)

Comment: and what about when the files dont arent showing extensions ??

Comment: @Trevor, do you think “`...txt`” is the extension of the file “`no....txt`”?

Comment: @КонстантинВан No. My guess is that most systems would recognize `no....txt` as a `txt` file. If you have a need to handle such edge cases, I would suggest: `filename.split('.').filter(Boolean).slice(1).join('.')`.

Answer (score 43):

**Update**

Since the original answer, [extname()](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_extname_p) has been added to the `path` module, see Snowfish answer

**Original answer:**

I'm using this function to get a file extension, because I didn't find a way to do it in an easier way (but I think there is) :

```
function getExtension(filename) {
    var ext = path.extname(filename||'').split('.');
    return ext[ext.length - 1];
}
```

you must require 'path' to use it.

another method which does not use the path module :

```
function getExtension(filename) {
    var i = filename.lastIndexOf('.');
    return (i < 0) ? '' : filename.substr(i);
}
```

Comment: Yeah that works. Just thought there would be an easier way using node. This is what i did: `var is = fs.createReadStream(req.files.upload.path), fileType = is.path.split(/[. ]+/).pop();`

Comment: You should really just use the path module, as @Snowfish's answer pointed out, and not write your own. More info: http://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_extname_p

Comment: and what about when the files dont arent showing extensions ??

Answer (score 29):

```
// you can send full url here
function getExtension(filename) {
    return filename.split('.').pop();
}
```

If you are using express please add the following line when configuring middleware (bodyParser)

```
app.use(express.bodyParser({ keepExtensions: true}));
```

Answer (score 18):

It's a lot more efficient to use the `substr()` method instead of `split()` & `pop()`

Have a look at the performance differences here: http://jsperf.com/remove-first-character-from-string

```
// returns: 'html'
var path = require('path');
path.extname('index.html').substr(1);
```

[image]

**Update August 2019**
As pointed out by @xentek in the comments; `substr()` is now considered a legacy function ([MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)). You can use `substring()` instead. The difference between `substr()` and `substring()` is that the second argument of `substr()` is the maximum length to return while the second argument of `substring()` is the index to stop at (without including that character). Also, `substr()` accepts negative start positions to be used as an offset from the end of the string while `substring()` does not.

Comment: There is a warning now for `substr` it is considered a legacy function and should be avoided when possible - [More information on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

Comment: When doing substr(1) test you should also take into consideration time spent for path.extname

Answer (score 15):

This solution supports querystrings!

```
var Url = require('url');
var Path = require('path');

var url = 'http://i.imgur.com/Mvv4bx8.jpg?querystring=true';
var result = Path.extname(Url.parse(url).pathname); // '.jpg'
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use [path.parse(path)](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_parse_path), for example

```
const path = require('path');
const { ext } = path.parse('/home/user/dir/file.txt');
```

Answer (score 7):

A simple solution without need for require which solves the multiple period extension problem:

```
var filename = 'file.with.long.extension';
var ext = filename.substring(filename.indexOf('.')); 
//ext = '.with.long.extension'
```

Or if you don't want the leading dot:

```
var filename = 'file.with.long.extension';
var ext = filename.substring(filename.indexOf('.')+1); 
//ext = 'with.long.extension'
```

Make sure to test that the file has an extension too.

Answer (score 6):

import extname in order to return the extension the file:

```
import { extname } from 'path';
extname(file.originalname);
```

where file is the file 'name' of form

Answer (score 4):

I do think mapping the Content-Type header in the request will also work. This will work even for cases when you upload a file with no extension.
(when filename does not have an extension in the request)

Assume you are sending your data using HTTP POST:

```
POST /upload2 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:7098
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1047799
Accept: */*
Origin: http://localhost:63342
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,    like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----   WebKitFormBoundaryPDULZN8DYK3VppPp
Referer: http://localhost:63342/Admin/index.html? _ijt=3a6a054pasorvrljf8t8ea0j4h
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,az;q=0.6,tr;q=0.4
Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundaryPDULZN8DYK3VppPp
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="blob"
Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundaryPDULZN8DYK3VppPp--
```

Here name Content-Type header contains the mime type of the data. 
Mapping this mime type to an extension will get you the file extension :).

Restify BodyParser converts this header in to a property with name **type**

```
File {
  domain: 
   Domain {
     domain: null,
     _events: { .... },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     members: [ ... ] },
  _events: {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  size: 1047621,
  path: '/tmp/upload_2a4ac9ef22f7156180d369162ef08cb8',
  name: 'blob',
  **type: 'image/png'**,
  hash: null,
  lastModifiedDate: Wed Jul 20 2016 16:12:21 GMT+0300 (EEST),
  _writeStream: 
  WriteStream {
   ... },
     writable: true,
     domain: 
     Domain {
        ...
     },
      _events: {},
      _eventsCount: 0,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     path: '/tmp/upload_2a4ac9ef22f7156180d369162ef08cb8',
     fd: null,
     flags: 'w',
     mode: 438,
     start: undefined,
     pos: undefined,
     bytesWritten: 1047621,
     closed: true } 
}
```

You can use this header and do the extension mapping (substring etc ...) manually, but there are also ready made libraries for this. Below two were the top results when i did a google search

- **mime**
- **mime-types**

and their usage is simple as well:

```
 app.post('/upload2', function (req, res) {
  console.log(mime.extension(req.files.image.type));
 }
```

above snippet will print **png** to console.

Answer (score 3):

A one liner which extends `String.prototype`:

```
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "ext", {get: function(x) {return this.split('.').pop()}})
str = 'fox.fbx';
str.ext
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`path.extname` will do the trick in most cases. However, it will include everything after the last `.`, including the query string and hash fragment of an http request:

```
var path = require('path')
var extname = path.extname('index.html?username=asdf')
// extname contains '.html?username=asdf'
```

In such instances, you'll want to try something like this:

```
var regex = /[#\\?]/g; // regex of illegal extension characters
var extname = path.extname('index.html?username=asdf');
var endOfExt = extname.search(regex);
if (endOfExt > -1) {
    extname = extname.substring(0, endOfExt);
}
// extname contains '.html'
```

Note that extensions with multiple periods (such as `.tar.gz`), will not work at all with `path.extname`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var fileName = req.files.upload.name;

var arr = fileName.split('.');

var extension = arr[length-1];
```

Comment: where does the length variable come from?

Comment: Try to add some explanation to your answer. That way, the OP can actually understand what you did and why you did this. That way the OP can learn from your answer, rather than just copy/pasting it.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const path = require('path');

function getExt(str) {
  const basename = path
    .basename(str)
    // Patch: for hidden files
    // Removes all dots at the beginning of a line
    .replace(/^(\.+)/i, '');

  const firstDot = basename.indexOf('.');
  const lastDot = basename.lastIndexOf('.');
  const extname = path.extname(basename).replace(/(\.[a-z0-9]+).*/i, '$1');

  if (firstDot === lastDot) {
    return extname;
  }

  return basename.slice(firstDot, lastDot) + extname;
}
```

```js
const files = [
  '/home/charlike/bar/.hidden.tar.gz~',     // ".tar.gz"
  '/home/charlike/bar/file.tar.gz~',        // ".tar.gz"
  '/home/charlike/bar/file.tar.gz+cdf2',    // ".tar.gz"
  '/home/charlike/bar/file.tar.gz?quz=zaz', // ".tar.gz"
];

const fileAndExt = files.map((file) => [ file, getExt(file) ]);

console.log(JSON.stringify(fileAndExt, null, 2));
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0):

The following function splits the string and returns the name and extension no matter how many dots there are in the extension. It returns an empty string for the extension if there is none. Names that start with dots and/or white space work also.

```
function basext(name) {
  name = name.trim()
  const match = name.match(/^(\.+)/)
  let prefix = ''
  if (match) {
    prefix = match[0]
    name = name.replace(prefix, '')
  }
  const index = name.indexOf('.')
  const ext = name.substring(index + 1)
  const base = name.substring(0, index) || ext
  return [prefix + base, base === ext ? '' : ext]
}

const [base, ext] = basext('hello.txt')
```

Comment: Doesn't work if filename contains dots like `2023-02-16 14.04.43.jpg` nor other characters like `file.gz~` or `file.gz+cdf2` as in examples of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60992310/3484824), not sure they make sense, though according to this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_filename_extensions) there's quite a few special characters possible like `--`, `++`, `#`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```js
const path = require('path');

function getExt(str) {
  const basename = path.basename(str);
  const firstDot = basename.indexOf('.');
  const lastDot = basename.lastIndexOf('.');
  const extname = path.extname(basename).replace(/(\.[a-z0-9]+).*/i, '$1');

  if (firstDot === lastDot) {
    return extname;
  }

  return basename.slice(firstDot, lastDot) + extname;
}

// all are `.gz`
console.log(getExt('/home/charlike/bar/file.gz'));
console.log(getExt('/home/charlike/bar/file.gz~'));
console.log(getExt('/home/charlike/bar/file.gz+cdf2'));
console.log(getExt('/home/charlike/bar/file.gz?quz=zaz'));

// all are `.tar.gz`
console.log(getExt('/home/charlike/bar/file.tar.gz'));
console.log(getExt('/home/charlike/bar/file.tar.gz~'));
console.log(getExt('/home/charlike/bar/file.tar.gz+cdf2'));
console.log(getExt('/home/charlike/bar/file.tar.gz?quz=zaz'));
```

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work if filename contains dots like `2023-02-16 14.04.43.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

Using `path` is not really reliable as it depends on extension name being in the file name, which is not always the case.

You should use [file-type package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type) it detects extension by checking the magic number of the buffer, rather than depending on name of the file which not always have extension in it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).