# Nodejs get file extension

Tags: node.js, file-extension

I have a folder with images and they can have different formats but the name will always be unique. Is there a way to get the file extension if I know the file's name **without** the extension (eg. `index` and **not** `index.html`)? I could just check if the file exists for every extension I expect to be there but that seems like a bad solution to me.

**Example**:
I know there is an image called `PIC` but I don't know the extension (could be either '.png', '.jpg' etc.) therefore I can not use the file command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js get file extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865347/node-js-get-file-extension)

Comment: I want to remove the flag but unfortunately can't. If a mod could reject that would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if your running Unix based systems, this could be a workaround.

```js
var sys = require('util')
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

function puts(error, stdout, stderr) { 
   console.log(stdout) 
}

// this is where you should get your path/filename
var filename = "login";
// execute unix command 'file'
exec("file " + filename, puts);
```

I tested it for a PNG file and an EJS file, both with no extensions (what wouldn't make difference).
The results are below:

**PNG:**
*photo: PNG image data, 100 x 100, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced*

**EJS (what's basically a HTML):**
*login: HTML document, ASCII text*

You can check **file** command line parameters to make it easier to work with the string (e.g. *file -b filename*).
If using Windows, then you'd have to check an alternative command for **file**.

Hope it's somehow useful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I did not ask my question specific enough, so I updated my question.

Comment: Can you use the command **dir** or **ls**? I mean, if you can work with operation system comands, the code snipped in the answer could be adapted to the OS command (e.g. ls index* OR dir index*).

Comment: add -b and --extension to get a list of possible extensions..tested on jpg without extension gave me `jpeg/jpg/jpe/jfif`

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party, but you can use the `grep` command in unix based systems.

ie `ls | grep PIC`. What this does is first give a directory listing of the working directory, and then searches for the phrase PIC from the output of the directory listing and prints it. (so the only thing that will be printed is the filename)

In Windows, use `dir PIC.* /b`

You can execute these commands using `child_process` as shown in other answers

Answer (score -1):

var path = require('path')

path.extname('index.html')
// returns
'.html'

Here is the referenced answer

[Node.js get file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865347/node-js-get-file-extension)

Updated :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-extension
npm install --save file-extension
allows you to specify a filename then it will return the extension

Comment: As stated in my question I do not know the file's extension. I just know there is a file called 'index.SOMETHING'.

Comment: $ npm install --save file-extension  here is the documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-extension