# How to get filename & save to disk in Hapi.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I wrote a Hapi.js route to receive an uploaded file and have called it successfully using Postman. Now I want to save the file.

How do I

1. get the file extension?
2. save the file to disk?

Here's my route:

```
{
      method: 'POST',
      path: this.config.apiPrefix + 'uploadprofilephoto',
      config: {   payload: { maxBytes: 10485760, /* 10 MB */  output: 'stream',   parse: true   } },
      handler: (request: hapi.Request, reply: hapi.IReply) =>  {
        const result = new Promise<string>( async (resolve, reject) => {
          try {
            this.profilePhotoRouteHelper.savePhotoAndUploadToAws(jwtData.userId, request.payload['image']);
            resolve(responseHelper.getSuccessResponse<string>(null, newJwt));
          }
          catch (error) {
            log.error(error);
            resolve(responseHelper.getErrorResponse(ResponseErrorCode.unknownError));
          }
        });
        reply(result);
      }
```

and an idea of how to save:

```
fs.writeFile(filename, data, [encoding], () => {      } );
```

but I'd rather use promises and await if possible.

Here's the uploaded file:

[image]

Comment: I would not use arrow functions for handler functions due to lexical this

Comment: We use almost exclusively arrow functions throughout our app and haven't had any problems

Comment: They should not be used with handlers as you lose the this context from hapi

Answer (score 1):

I found [fs-promise](https://github.com/kevinbeaty/fs-promise), which works well.

```
  const photoId = uuid.v4();
  await fsp.writeFile(photoId + '__' + image.hapi.filename, image._data, 'utf8');
```

And here's how to get file extensions: [Node.js get file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865347/node-js-get-file-extension)