# How to get file extension from file content using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need some help. I need to fetch what the file type should be from the file containing only using Node.js. I am explaining the scenario below.

Let's say I have some content like below.

```
let fileContent = "The textContent property sets or returns the text content of the specified node, and all its descendants."
```

As we can see here the variable `fileContent` has some text data and I want to write this data into one file. So for that, I need to create the file with a proper extension like `abc.txt`. Similarly, If `fileContent` has some `json` data then I will create the file like `abc.json` and write the value inside it.

So here I need to fetch what should be the `type` of file from this content only using `Node.js`. If anybody has a solution for this will be a great help.

Comment: If you want something more than just JSON and text it doesn't seem like there would be one liner solution. You need ML here or an existing product that gives you service to use their API.

Comment: Follow this question and answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865347/node-js-get-file-extension

Answer (score 1):

You can use popular [file-type](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type) package for this. You can send buffer/file/stream/blob as an input and get file type as an output.

```js
const FileType = require('file-type');
...
const { ext, mime } = await FileType.fromBuffer(your_data);
```