# Image Extension missing in image upload

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working with nodejs/Express js, I am trying to upload image using "API", Image is uploading but extension is missing in "image name", How can i fix this issue ? Here is my current code

```
var storage =   multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './uploads');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
      console.log('data is'+ file.ext);
    callback(null, file.ext + '-' + Date.now());
  }
});

 var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).any('userPhoto');
 const uploadavatar = function (req, res) {
    upload(req,res,function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return res.end("Error uploading file." + err);
        }
        res.end("File is uploaded");
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the file name and extension in the callback:
It should be:
`

```
callback(null, Date.now().toString() + '.' + file.ext);
```

`file.ext` will only contain the extension, so your code will return sth like image.jpg would become  `jpg-1681569703491`

Comment: now image uploading but name is "1681553706040.undefined" , means file.ext not working

Comment: you have to be sure of the output of `file.ext` console.log is helpful here! I guess it is better to look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865347/node-js-get-file-extension)

Comment: i am getting "undefined" after console.log(file.ext)