# Nodejs, to get file type of a file

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems, file-type

The six-year-old question "[Node.js - File System get file type, solution around year 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431845/)" has a better answer but the outdated answer was the correct one by then.

Hence the question, for an up-to-date solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OPTION 1: If you want the mimetype**:

Install

```
npm i -S file-type read-chunk
```

Use

```
const readChunk = require('read-chunk');
const fileType = require('file-type');

const buffer = readChunk.sync(filePath, 0, fileType.minimumBytes);
console.log(fileType(buffer));
```

**OPTION 2: If you just need the would-be file extension**:

Install

```
npm i -S image-size
```

Use

```
const sizeOf = require('image-size');
console.log(sizeOf(filePath).type);
```

Comment: *file-type* doesn't work. just tried and it correctly returns `mime":"application/x-msdownload"` for windows dll, but it returns `undefined` for binaries, on which the `file` command correctly returns `ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64...`

Comment: I tried this solution (both Option 1 and 2) for a file of type txt and it just returned _undefined_ .

Comment: Text files don't need to have a header, hence you cannot determine the type by using methods which use file headers.